# Using JOIN on three tables - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My tables are arranged as follows. I am only showing one value in each of them for simplicity.

**Table: Events**

```
Event_ID   Event_Title
1          Broad Street Gathering
```

**Table: EventUserTags**

```
User_ID  Event_ID
10092    1
```

**Table: UserLinks**

```
User_1  User_2
10092   29809
```

***If the ID of the current user is 10092:***

1) Select ID's from **UserLinks** where **User_1** or **User_2** is 10092, (if User_1 is 10092, then select User_2)

2) Select the **Event_ID**'s from **EventUserTags** using the User_ID's (obtained above)

3) Select the **Event_Title** from **Events** using the Event_ID's (obtained above)

So, for example:

**If the logged-in user has an ID of 10092, this query will obtain the Event_Title "Broad Street Gathering"**

So far, I have not had any luck. Any help whatsoever is appreciated

A user from this website recommended using:

```
SELECT
   Event_Title,
   Event_ID,
   User_1,
   User_2
    FROM
   Events
   NATURAL JOIN EventUserTags
   JOIN UserLinks ON (
          User_ID = User_1 AND User_2 = $id
          OR User_ID = User_2 AND User_1 = $id
       )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that sometimes you're joining tables using `User_1` and sometimes `User_2`, which is not an easy concept to express in a join condition.

Instead, you can do two separate `SELECT`s and then `UNION` them together to get a single result set.

```
 SELECT UL.User_1 AS User_ID, EUT.Event_ID, E.Event_Title
 FROM UserLinks UL 
      INNER JOIN EventUserTags EUT ON UL.User_1 = EUT.User_ID
      INNER JOIN Events E ON E.Event_ID = EUT_Event_ID
 WHERE UL.User_1 = :user_id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT UL.User_2 AS User_ID, EUT.Event_ID, E.Event_Title
 FROM UserLinks UL 
      INNER JOIN EventUserTags EUT ON UL.User_2 = EUT.User_ID
      INNER JOIN Events E ON E.Event_ID = EUT_Event_ID
 WHERE UL.User_2 = :user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the setup of your UserLinks table.
You really should have:

```
user_id  link
1        10092
2        29809
```

Then you could very easily use:

```
SELECT e.* tags.*, user.*
FROM Events e
JOIN EventUserTags tags
ON tags.event_id=e.event_id
JOIN UserLinks user
ON user.user_id=tags.user_id
WHERE user.user_id=$id
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to see how your UserLinks table associates the two IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.Event_Title, e.Event_ID, 
       COALESCE(ul1.User_1, ul2.User_1) AS User_1,
       COALESCE(ul1.User_2, ul2.User_2) AS User_2
    FROM EventUserTags eut
        INNER JOIN Events e
            ON eut.Event_ID = e.Event_ID
        LEFT JOIN UserLinks ul1
            ON eut.User_ID = ul1.User_1
        LEFT JOIN UserLinks ul2
            ON eut.User_ID = ul2.User_2
    WHERE eut.User_ID = $id
        AND (ul1.User_1 IS NOT NULL OR ul2.User_2 IS NOT NULL)
```